# svn: E175013: Access to url forbidden

Tags: apache, svn, centos7

I'm running a CentOS 7 server distibution with svn 1.7.14. I have a directory index like this one:

```
www
    rootDir
        dir1
            repo1_1
            repo2_1
            repo3_1
        dir2
        repo1
```

And in /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-subversion.conf I have something like this:

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so
LoadModule dontdothat_module  modules/mod_dontdothat.so

<Location /rootDir>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/www/rootDir/
    AuthName Name
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
    Require valid-user
</Location>

<Location /rootDir/dir1>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/www/rootDir/dir1/
    AuthName Name
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I have no problem connecting to repo1 but when I try with repo1_1 and the rest I get a Forbidden message. (svn: E175013: Access to 'http://localhost/rootDir/dir1/repo1_1' forbidden)
I read that this problem could be caused by the modul mod_evasive but I didn't find anything about this module in the httpd.conf file

The owner of rootDir and all the subfolders is Apache user